# Set TextView width equal to ImageView width within LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout, android-linearlayout

I got the following code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/slider_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.6"/>

<TextView
    style="@style/DefaultText"
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.4"/>
```

(Because I don't know the size of the image yet, thats why I have to set the size of the ImageView via `layout_weight`.)
The code snippet results in:

```
|-------------------|
|     |       |     |
|     | IMAGE |     |
|     |       |     |
|-------------------|
|                   |
|   <<<  TEXT  >>>  |
|                   |
|-------------------|
```

What I want to get:

```
|-------------------|
|     |       |     |
|     | IMAGE |     |
|     |       |     |
|-------------------|
|     |       |     |
|     | TEXT  |     |
|     |       |     |
|-------------------|
```

I am not sure if it's possible in plain XML or if I have to use Java therefor.

Anyways - I can't make use of RelativeLayout's `layout_alignLeft` and `layout_alignRight` because I have to set the ImageView height first.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The `ImageVIew` in your layout takes the entire width of the parent `LinearLayout`, whatever that is. It may not appear that way if the image content doesn't fill that entire width, but the view itself is still as wide as the parent.

Comment: that's true but is there a way to set parents width equal to the ImageView width in that case? Or do I have the wrong approach in general?

Comment: I can't think of anything that only uses layouts provided by the framework.

Comment: Seems like I have to set the width programmatically in the activity onCreate()

Answer (score 0):

You can use a RelativeLayout as parent and just put the following lines for the textview

```
    android:layout_below="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/icon"
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is that, you want your `ImageView` & `TextView` of same width.

There are two ways to achieve that.

1. **Through XML**: In your XML file for your `ImageView` set `scaleType` property,

   `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

   this will ensure that your image will fit into your `ImageView` & `ImageView` width will not vary.
2. **Through JAVA**: After setting the image to `ImageView` get dimensions of `ImageView` and set same dimensions to your `TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/slider_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_weight="0.6" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Textview"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4" />
</LinearLayout>
```